# Изменяю регистрацию. Даже не заходит в контроллер

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Изменяю шаблонную регистрацию в MVC. Но он даже не заходит в контроллер `Register(RegisterViewModel model)` при нажатии на форме регистрация. 
В чем может быть дело?

Модель:

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Имя")]
[StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Требуется длина имени не менее {2} символов.", MinimumLength = 2)]
public string UserName { get; set; }

[Required]
[Remote("CheckUserName", "Account")] 
[Display(Name = "Email")]
public string Email { get; set; }

 [Required]
 [DataType(DataType.Password)]
 [Display(Name = "Пароль")]
 public string Password { get; set; }
```

Вью:

```
      @using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <h4>Create a new account.</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
 ....
  <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Register" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Контроллер

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.Email };
        var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            AddErrors(result);
        }
    }
   return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Провертье что происходит на клиенте, с помощью dev tools / firebug. Посмотрите, уходит ли запрос на сервер. Если уходит - то посмотрите что приходит в ответ.

Comment: _Изменяю шаблонную регистрацию_ - что именно поменяли? все ли обязательные поля ввели при проверке?

Comment: @PashaPash проверил с помощью dev tools в хроме. Ничего не уходит

Comment: @Grundy добавил поля (имя, фамилию, отчество...) в модели Account и изменил в контроллере  было var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.Name }; изменил на model.Email . При проверке вводил все поля.

Comment: если ничего не уходит, то скорее всего сработала какая-нибудь клиентская валидация, что-то вроде jQuery Unobtrusive Validation, попробуйте отключить ее

Comment: @Grundy Спасибо!! Все работает!) Буду искать где валидация срабатывает

Comment: если вы нашли решение, можете добавить его как свой собственный ответ и пометить его как принятый